# When I import a table from R to Excel the numbers change from this 1.6329932 to this 16.329.932.?

Tags: microsoft-excel, format, characters

When I import a table from R to Excel the numbers change from this 1.6329932 to this 16.329.932.??? I need to convert 16.329.932 back to 1.6329932. the table has a lot of values and all have changed except the ones starting with 0. could you please help me in this.
Thanks a lot
Isidro

Comment: How are you importing them exactly?

Comment: Assuming you're importing from a text file, Excel has a "text import wizard". You need to define as a decimal separator the `.` character.

Comment: Thanks a lot Doktoro! I use the "text import wizard" I defined as decimal separator the "." and as thousand separator the ",". and it worked! @DoktoroReichard thanks a lot for the help! :-)